# What is the best method of visualising binary classification preditcions?

Tags: data-visualization, binary-data, graphical-model

I have 2 columns in a dataset, "Device" and "Classification". I want to plot a graph that shows how well the "Classification" result is predicted given the data in the "Device" column.

Both columns contain only 1 or 0.

I have made an idea of the graph below, but have no idea if such a graph exists?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The graph you are talking about basically is a modified version of the confusion matrix.

For a reference have a look at [scikit-learn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_confusion_matrix.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-model-selection-plot-confusion-matrix-py).